# multiple windows to 1 single window batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have 2 batch files I want to merge from 2 screens to 1 screen.

currently there is 2 screens:
1 screen is the chat room
1 screen is the message input screen.

I want to merge these into 1 batch file on the screen so it requests users input on the chat room screen
is that possible?

My code I want to merge is here:

```
----------------------------
chat.bat
----------------------------

@echo off

:StartUp
set rr=2
mode con cols=40 lines=8
if exist tmp.bat del /f /s /q tmp.bat
set hd=%cd%
title Remote Chat
color 0f
cls
echo [Remote Chat]
echo.
echo Made by Jordan Begg
echo 31/12/2013
set t1=%time:~6,2%
set /a t2=%t1%+2
if %t2% geq 60 set /a t2=%t2% - 59
:ExpLoop
if %time:~6,2% geq %t2% goto Go
goto ExpLoop
:Go
set cs=ChatSettings.bat
if exist %cs% (
call %cs%
goto Main
) else (
goto SetUp
)

:SetUp
cls
mkdir "C:\chat"
echo [Setup]
echo.
set /p un=Username: 
if not defined un goto SetUp
:SetUp2
cls
echo [Setup]
echo.
echo Use this:
echo C:\chat 
if defined sd echo Current: %sd%
echo.
set /p sd=Server folder: 
if not defined sd goto SetUp2
set sd=%sd%
if not exist %sd% (
set sd=
echo Folder doesn't exist!
pause >nul
goto SetUp2
)
if exist %cs% del /f /s /q %cs%
echo set un=%un%>>%cs%
echo set sd=%sd%>>%cs%
echo set rr=4>>%cs%
goto Main

:Main
cd %hd%
cls
echo [Remote Chat]
echo.
echo 1 - Join
echo 2 - Create
echo 4 - Exit
echo.
set /p c=
if %c%==1 goto Join
if %c%==2 goto create1
if %c%==4 goto Exit
goto main

:Exit
exit





:create1
cls
echo Please enter a valid asset ID (i.e as0123456)
set /p ass=Asset:
ping -n 1 %ass% > c:\ping.tmp
type c:\ping.tmp | FIND "Approximate round trip" >NUL
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO NOPING
goto Create
:noping
echo Asset cannot be reached
echo.
goto create1


:Create
cd %sd%
set rn=
cls
echo [Create]
echo.
echo created
echo.
set rn=%ass%
echo %rn%
pause 
if not defined rn goto Create
set rf=%sd%\%rn%.crm
if exist %rf% goto Create
cls
echo [Create]
echo.
echo Preparing room, please wait.
set group=Admin
echo [%time:~0,5%] %un% (admin) connected.>>%rf%
title Chat [%rn%]
cd %hd%
echo set rn=%rn%>>tmp.bat
echo set rf=%rf%>>tmp.bat
echo set group=%group%>>tmp.bat
start ChatMessage.bat
start ChatDisconnect.bat
cd %sd%
mode con cols=40 lines=16
:Admin
cls
cd %hd% >nul
if not exist tmp.bat (
set msg=Room closed successfully.
goto End
)
cd %sd% >nul
if not exist %rf% (
set msg=Connection terminated.
goto End
)
type %rf%
ping localhost -n 4 >nul
goto Admin

set t=%time:~7,1%+%rr%
if %t% GEQ 10 set /a t=%t% - 10
:AdminL
if %time:~7,1%==%t% goto Admin

:End
if exist tmp.bat del /f /s /q tmp.bat
mode con cols=40 lines=8
echo [Chat]
echo.
echo %msg%
set msg=
taskkill /f /fi "WINDOWTITLE eq Message" >nul
taskkill /f /fi "WINDOWTITLE eq Disconnect" >nul
title Chat
set group=
set rn=
set t1=%time:~6,2%
set /a t2=%t1%+2
if %t2% geq 60 set /a t2=%t2% - 5
:EndLoop
if %time:~6,2% geq %t2% goto Main
goto EndLoop

:Join
mode con cols=40 lines=16
cd %sd%
set rn=
cls
echo [Join]
echo.
if not exist %sd%\*crm (
echo No rooms available.
pause >nul
mode con cols=40 lines=8
goto Main
)
dir /b /o:n %sd%\*.crm
echo.
echo Format (no .crm at end): Room
set /p rn=Room's name: 
if not defined rn goto Join
set rf=%sd%\%rn%.crm
if not exist %rf% goto Join
cls
echo [Join]
echo.
echo Joining room, please wait.
set group=User
echo [%time:~0,5%] %un% connected.>>%rf%
title Chat [%rn%]
cd %hd%
echo set rn=%rn%>>tmp.bat
echo set rf=%rf%>>tmp.bat
echo set group=%group%>>tmp.bat
start ChatMessage.bat
start ChatDisconnect.bat
cd %sd%
:User
cls
cd %hd% >nul
if not exist tmp.bat (
set msg=Disconnected successfully.
goto End
)
cd %sd% >nul
if not exist %rf% (
set msg=Connection terminated.
goto End
)
type %rf%
ping localhost -n 4 >nul
goto User
```

.

```
-----------------------
chatmessage.bat
------------------------


@echo off
if not exist tmp.bat (
exit
) else (
call tmp.bat
call ChatSettings.bat
)
title Message
mode con cols=30 lines=2
cd %sd%
:func
cls
set /p msg=Message: 
if %msg:~0,3%==/me echo [%time:~0,5%] %un% %msg:~4%>>%rf%&& goto func
if not defined msg goto func
echo [%time:~0,5%] %un%: %msg%>>%rf%
goto func
```

Comment: Please make the problem short and clear. It is too long and confusing me.

Comment: Unfortunately, you've asked a very good question quite poorly. it's unnecessary to include all of your code, you need to only include relevant sections. I don't have an answer for you, if your question doesn't get answered I'll probably end up asking it some time down the track. For now - if you are able to use a different programming language, I suggest you try that.